# VBA macro to change filters in pivot table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I'm trying do automate a daily report and therefore I want to create two buttons which change the filters of three pivot tables. In detail the buttons shall change the day which is shown. The first filters on yesterday the second one is a reset button do clear all filters and show all days.
The "Resest"-Button is working but the "Yesterday"-Button not.

At the moment the macro looks like that:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range("B1")
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Detail_Digital").PivotFields("Tag").CurrentPage = _
    ACtiveSheet.Range("B1").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

I've also tried `PivotFilters.Add _ , Type:=xlDateYesterday` but that isn't working either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What error is it giving you? Could be a date parsing issue...especially if you are outside the US. 

I've answered a question similar to this at the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105890/filtering-multiple-pivot-tables-based-on-drop-down-selections-using-vba/39111413#39111413

Comment: Again thank you. I'll have a look on the other question in a few minute. For the Code above there is no error message. It's just doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, it should work, unless your "Date" is formatted differently between the Pivot's data source and `Range("B1")`.

**Note**: try to avoid using `ActiveSheet`, instead use referenced objects. In the case below, replace `Worksheets("Sheet1")` with your sheet's name.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim PvtTbl      As PivotTable
Dim PvtItm      As PivotItem

' set the Pivot Table
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("Detail_Digital")

With PvtTbl
    .PivotFields("Tag").ClearAllFilters ' <-- clear all filters to "Tag"
    'Debug.Print Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
    For Each PvtItm In .PivotFields("Tag").PivotItems
        If PvtItm.Name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value Then
            PvtItm.Visible = True
        Else
            PvtItm.Visible = False
        End If
    Next PvtItm
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your help! But in some cases there's a problem with the `PvtItm.Visible = False`. For example if every item is visible there's an error but the filter is changed to the value of B1. But if there's already a filter it gives the error and doesn't change the filter to the value of B1.

Comment: @Heaf does it work some of the times ? or fails all the times ?

Comment: Sometimes it works. But it gives the same error al the time

Comment: Now it's working all the time but still gives the same error. "runtime error 1004 unable to set the visible property of the pivotitem class"

Comment: @Heaf it filters correclty  and gives this error ? at what line ?

Comment: Yep it filters correctly but gives this error at `PvtItm.Visible = False`

Comment: @Heaf try closing all excel instances, and start this file again. I can't figre out why. Do you have other module referncing the same `PivotTable` ?

Comment: Still the same.. very strange. Could it be that the code tries to set the visible property of "all" to false? Which isn't possible because there's at least one item with "visible = true" (the item in B1)? Hope you understand what I'm meaning. Or is it a problem that I have the code right inside of the Button? I could try to put it in a modul and just call it.. And the only other modul would be the mentioned "Reset"-Button but this should'nt be a problem I guess.

Comment: @Heaf don't think so. Is this code button inside a regular module ? or a worksheet code module ?

Comment: Both codes ("reset" and "yesterday") are inside the worksheet module.

Comment: @Heaf it shouldn't effect, even though I rather have my code (except worksheet related events) in regular module code

Comment: @Heaf not sure how I can help, I'm not getting this error, but I'm running this code from a regular module

Comment: hm I put the code in a regular module (still inside of this VBA project not the personal one) and just put a `call Yesterday`in the CommandButton but theres still the error.. also tried some other suggestions from SO where people had the same problem.. but still the error.. I'll keep trying and will comment when it's solved.. But you've been a great help @Shai thank you!

Comment: @Heaf your'e welcome, it if at the ends this code works without error, don't forget to "tick" this "Answer"

Comment: Already "ticked" it but I`m a Newbie here so SO just records my votes without showing them ;)

Comment: you can only click as "answer"  on the **V** next to my answer, and it will turn green. you can't upvote, yet...

Comment: You get that error when there is just one visible PivotItem, and the code attempts to hide it. You can't hide all pivotitems at one time...you need to ensure that at least one is visible. So I normally make the last PivotItem visible at the start of the code.

Comment: @jeffreyweir  that's why I have the clearallfilters in the beginning. If there are no matches, there should be another type of error handling, message box or something

Comment: ClearAllFilters won't help in the event that there isn't a PivotItem for the specific day that is being filtered on, which is what I presume is happening here.

Comment: Also note that iterating through PivotItems like you are doing is slow on two counts: Firstly, the PIvotTable will recalculate after each and every PivotItem is hidden unless you set .ManualUpdate to TRUE before the loop, and back to FALSE afterwards. Secondly, if you want to select just one item it's much faster to make the field you want to select on a PageField, and then use the .CurrentPage setting to select that one thing, along the lines of the original code posted by the op. This saves having to iterate through the PivotItems at all. I'll post an example when I get a moment.

Comment: @Shai...yes I did. I'm just pointing out why the code as posted is failing.

Comment: @jeffreyweir thanks for your comment. But the Code of Shai isn't failing. It's working quite well beside the runtime error. As I already mentioned above the filtering is correct. Couldn't find a solution for the problem until yet.