# Automatic update of calculated fields (Excel Pivot table)

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I am creating a top 10 product by sales calculation off of a pivot table I am running. My question is, I would like this table to populate automatically to the latest week when I refresh the table and am not sure how to do this.

Furthermore, there are some additional calculations like YoY growth for the particular product against the current week last year, 3 month growth, etc.. that I am note sure will update properly when placing in the new data.

I have attached a dummy file so you can get an idea of what I am working with.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1q9aqhn6rsn9hv/pivot-questions.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the date filtering, see my answer at [Filtering pivot table with vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004607/filtering-pivot-table-with-vba)
In regards to the calculations, if you use a paramatized GETPIVOTDATA function then you can easily accomplish what you want.